# Dagger inject wrong class (inject parent instead of children class)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm working on several app that connecting to the same API, so I decided to create common classes, put them in a module and share them among all projects.

For example, I have classes like following in my share module

```
// This is a bass class, no application will use it.
public class GetPlayerInteractor extends ApiInteractor {

  @Inject
  public GetPlayerInteractor(ThreadExecutor threadExecutor,
                             PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread,
                             RestClient restClient,
                             RequestTokenInteractor requestTokenInteractor) {
    super(threadExecutor, postExecutionThread, restClient, requestTokenInteractor);
  }
}

// This class will accept GetPlayerInteractor or its children class as argument.
public class PlayerAuthenticationInteractor extends ApiInteractor {

  @Inject
  public PlayerAuthenticationInteractor(ThreadExecutor threadExecutor,
                                        PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread,
                                        RestClient restClient,
                                        RequestTokenInteractor requestTokenInteractor,
                                        GetPlayerInteractor getPlayerInteractor) {
    super(threadExecutor, postExecutionThread, restClient, requestTokenInteractor,
        getPlayerInteractor);
  }
}
```

and in the application that include the module

```
// This one is the actual class I need to inject
public class GetPlayerByEmailInteractor extends GetPlayerInteractor {

  private GetDomainNameInteractor getDomainNameInteractor;

  @Inject
  public GetPlayerByEmailInteractor(ThreadExecutor threadExecutor,
                                    PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread,
                                    RestClient restClient,
                                    RequestTokenInteractor requestTokenInteractor,
                                    GetDomainNameInteractor getDomainNameInteractor) {
    super(threadExecutor, postExecutionThread, restClient, requestTokenInteractor, getPlayerCustomFieldsInteractor);

    this.getDomainNameInteractor = getDomainNameInteractor;
  }
}
```

And this is the UserModule in the application

```
@Module
public class UserModule {

  @Provides
  @PerActivity
  GetPlayerInteractor provideGetPlayerInteractor(ThreadExecutor threadExecutor,
                                                 PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread,
                                                 RestClient restClient,
                                                 RequestTokenInteractor requestTokenInteractor,
                                                 GetDomainNameInteractor getDomainNameInteractor) {
    Log.i("Dev", "Create GetPlayerInteractor");
    return new GetPlayerByEmailInteractor(threadExecutor, postExecutionThread, restClient, requestTokenInteractor, getDomainNameInteractor);
  }

  @Provides
  @PerActivity
  PlayerAuthenticationInteractor providePlayerAuthenticationInteractor(ThreadExecutor threadExecutor,
                                                                       PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread,
                                                                       RestClient restClient,
                                                                       RequestTokenInteractor requestTokenInteractor,
                                                                       GetPlayerByEmailInteractor getPlayerByEmailInteractor) {
    Log.i("Dev", "Create PlayerAuthenticationInteractor");
    return new PlayerAuthenticationInteractor(threadExecutor, postExecutionThread, restClient, requestTokenInteractor, getPlayerByEmailInteractor);
  }
}
```

And I never write @Provide for GetPlayerInteractor because it's just a base class but for some reason, GetPlayerByEmailInteractor never created, log in both Provide methods never print (also break point that I set never toggle) and I got getPlayerInteractor as an argument of PlayerAuthen instead of getPlayerByEmailInteractor.

Also, if I remove both

```
@Provide
@PerActivity
GetPlayerInteractor provideGetPlayerInteractor(...)
```

and

```
@Provide
@PerActivity
PlayerAuthenticationInteractor providePlayerAuthenticationInteractor(...)
```

The build still success, and the app can be run

When I look at DaggerApplicationComponent, I see as following

```
public final class DaggerApplicationComponent implements ApplicationComponent {
  // Some other classes
  private Provider<GetPlayerInteractor> getPlayerInteractorProvider;
  private Provider<PlayerAuthenticationInteractor> playerAuthenticationInteractorProvider;
  // Some other classes
  private Provider<GetPlayerByEmailInteractor> getPlayerByEmailInteractorProvider;
  // Some other classes

  private void initialize(final Builder builder) {
  // Some other classes
  this.getPlayerInteractorProvider = ...
  this.playerAuthenticationInteractorProvider = PlayerAuthenticationInteractor_Factory.create((MembersInjector) MembersInjectors.noOp(), provideThreadExecutorProvider, providePostExecutionThreadProvider, provideRestClientProvider, provideRequestTokenInteractorProvider, getPlayerInteractorProvider);
  // Some other classes
  this.getPlayerByEmailInteractorProvider = ...

    }
}
```

Note that the lass parameter that pass to PlayerAuthenticationInteractor_Factory is **getPlayerInteractorProvider** instead of **getPlayerByEmailInteractorProvider**.

What I'm I wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
UserPresenter provideUserPresenter(GetUserUseCase getUserUseCase)
```

Will tell dagger that you want a `GetUserUseCase`.

```
@Inject
public GetEmployeeUseCase()

@Inject
public GetEmployeeUseCase()
```

**Both** your `GetUserUseCase` and its child can be provided through constructor injection, but since you requested a `GetUserUseCase` this is what you get.

If you don't want to use `GetUserUseCase` don't request it. The easy way would be to fix your provides method to this:

```
UserPresenter provideUserPresenter(GetEmployeeUseCase getUserUseCase)
```

Which is kind of okay, since the logic of *what* you provide still is in a module and not in your business logic. If you want / have to provide your superclass, remove the `@Provides` from it and make a provides method like the following to tell dagger about the subclass that you want to use:

```
@Provides GetUserUseCase provideUserUseCase(GetEmployeeUseCase getUserUseCase) {
    return getUserUseCase;
}
```

This will just map your sub class implementation to the parent class. If you don't remove the `@Inject` annotation on your parent, this will lead to some *multiple provides methods...* error.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer but unfortunately its not working because the method to provide UserPresenter, I already request for GetEmployeeUseCase class. I'll update the code with my actual classes so that it might be better to see what I missed.

Comment: Question updated, sorry for not provide actual classes in the beginning.

Comment: @Tar_Tw45 please try removing the `@Inject` annotations on your classes constructors. as mentioned, your object is probably constructor injected-> your provides method gets ignored

Comment: I tried to remove that but the build failed, error says "cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method"

Comment: @Tar_Tw45 so add a method to your module as described in the bottom of my answer and it should work